# Rounding when [int] = [float] + [int] (Obj-C, iOS?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, rounding, floating-point-precision

In this case:

```
float a = 0.99999f;
int b = 1000;
int c = a + b;
```

In result `c = 1001`. I discovered that it happens because `b` is converted to float (specific for iOS), then `a + b` doesn't have enough precision for `1000.9999` and (**why?**) is rounded to higher value. If `a` is `0.999f` we get `c = 1000` - theoretically correct behavior.

So my question is why float number is rounded to higher value? Where this behavior (or convention) is described?

I tested this on iPhone Simulator, Apple LLVM 4.2 compiler.

Comment: here i'm getting 1000.

Comment: My mistake, people. `a = 0.99999f`

Comment: `int c = (int)a + b;` it gives me `1000`, even if the `a` is `0.9999999f`

Comment: @holex - Try `(int) (a + b)`.

Comment: @HotLicks, I've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `int c = a + b`, the integer `b` is converted to a float first, then 2 floating point
numbers are added, and the result is truncated to an integer.

The default floating point rounding mode is `FE_TONEAREST`, which means that the result
of the addition

```
0.99999f + 1000f
```

is the ***nearest*** number that can be represented as a float, and that is the number `1001f`. This float is then truncated to the integer `c = 1001`.

If you change the rounding mode

```
#include <fenv.h>
fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
```

then the result of the addition is rounded downward (approximately `1000.99993f`) and you would get `c = 1000`.

Comment: Close, but not quite right.  The *nearest* value to represent the result of the float addition is something like 1001.000032 (pulling a number out of the air), so the result is rounded to that.  That number is then *truncated* to 1001 on the float->int conversion, per standard C rules.

Comment: @HotLicks: I don't quite understand. Why should the nearest float to 0.99999 + 1000 be 1001.000032 and not 1001 ? 1001 *is* representable as a float, and is nearer to 1000.99999 than 1001.000032. (I also verified this in the debugger before giving the answer.) - Perhaps I am missing something completely?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right -- small integers are exactly representable in IEEE float.  But it needs to be emphasized that the rounding that occurs is in converting a float value to the nearest IEEE representation, not rounding to integer.  The rounding is, in essence, to 1001.00000, not 1001.

Comment: @HotLicks: I see your point. That is what I meant with *"the nearest number that can be represented as a float, and that is the number `1001f`"*. So with "float" I meant the C type `float` which is the IEEE float. I have changed the answer slightly to stress the fact that the truncation to int is a separate step. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you add 1000 you get 8 total decimal digits of precision, but IEEE float is only supports 7 digits.

Comment: But why the number is rounded? Outlying digits should be cut off (like in `float` -> `int` conversion).

Comment: @brigadir - In essence, the sum is computed using a much greater precision, and may produce a result of 1000.9999932, let's say.  But that cannot be represented as a 32-bit float.  So the two nearest "legal" values may be 1000.9999843 and 1001.0000017.  In default rounding mode, the FP unit picks the latter, since it's closer to the "real" answer.